# How to hide my eth balance

Tags: ether, erc-20, ethereum-wallet-dapp, myetherwallet, etherscan

i want to hide my eth balance from myetherwallet, etherscan , ethplorer .how to hide my eth balance in my ether wallet , etherscan , ethplorer. 
any methods available, please reply

thanks

Answer (score 4):

Everything in the blockchain is public information. Therefore you can't directly hide it.

That being said, you *can* send your Ether balance to multiple wallets. That way your one wallet will not display your "full" balance. But, as the transactions are also public, anyone can see that Ether was sent away from one wallet and into another and if they want, they can just go and see the balance of the other wallet. But it's almost impossible for people to know which wallets are yours and which are other people's.

Comment: hi ,      please check this image url                                                                https://imgur.com/a/kRc3YXL     .                                                                                                   in this account balance exists.last three incoming transaction combines 0.027 ETH . But showing balance is 0.00000000000016026 ETH

Comment: If you would give the address, anyone could check and tell you what has happened there. But if an account has 0.027 ETH incoming, it has to have some ETH also outgoing if the actual balance is less than that. Or then then viewer you use is broken.

Comment: this is the address  0xA8015DF1F65E1f53D491dC1ED35013031AD25034  .     what is the issue . it has 0.1 ETH .But showing balance is 0.0000000000009000 ETH....WHY

Comment: I think you're just using some crappy blockchain explorer. Have a look at https://etherscan.io/address/0xA8015DF1F65E1f53D491dC1ED35013031AD25034 and you see everything is ok. There are more than 8000 transactions, so I'm not going to count the Ether balance by hand. If you have any further questions, please open a new question.